# How to remove comma from HashSet String java

Tags: java, string, data-structures

I have a HashSet String  ['a','b','c'].  How can I print the String `abc`?

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<Character>h=new HashSet<>();
        h.add('a');
        h.add('b');
        h.add('c');

        // if here i am print HashSet element then print 

        System.out.println(h); //[a,b,c]

       // now i HashSet convert in String 

        String res=h.toString();    

        // when i try to print String then print [a,b,c]

        System.out.println(res);        // [a,b,c] 
      //but i am not interest in this result becuase i wnat to print only  abc remove all brackets [] ,and , commas 
}
```

Comment: What is a "HashSet String?"  Please include some actual Java code here.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining()

Comment: Does this string result from calling `toString()` on a `HashSet`? If so, don't do that but construct the String yourself by concatenating the values without the comma.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove commas from the result of a `HashSet`'s `toString()`, e.g. `"['a','b','c']"`?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use String.join() as followed

```
System.out.println(String.join("",h));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 8** or later then you can use **Java Stream API**, or *Iterable.forEach()*:

```
public class HashSetExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
        System.out.println("System.out.println(set): " + set);
        System.out.print("Using .forEach() method: ");
        set.forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Using Stream API: ");
        set.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output will be:

[image]